# How to make a chunked transfer encoding HTTP request in Android?

Tags: android, http

How to generate a chunked transfer encoding HTTP request in Android ? The code below did not do the trick for me.

```
    HttpURLConnection  cn = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url)).openConnection();  
    cn.setRequestProperty("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
```

Comment: Does the URL you are connecting to support returning chunked transfer encoded data? Can you use cURL or wget or some other language and get chunked transfer encoded data by just setting the header?

Answer (score 1):

You can't request that the response is chunked. The server isn't even required to be able to generate chunked response.

What you are doing by sending that header, is telling the server that the content of the *request* is in chunked encoding.